# Django form is rendering via AJAX but with no data inside fields

Tags: django, ajax

I'm trying to render a Django form with AJAX :

Here are my files :

Models.py

```
class models_projects(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table_projects'
```

Forms.py

```
class forms_projects(forms.ModelForm):
    id = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"id", "class":"form-control"}), label="id")
    reference = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"reference", "class":"form-control"}), label="reference")
    model = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"model", "class":"form-control"}), label="model")

    class Meta:
        model = models_projects
        exclude = ("user",)
```

View.py

```
def update_project_mobile(request):

    project_id = request.POST.get('project_num')

    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        record = models_projects.objects.get(id = project_id) 
        projects_form = forms_projects(request.POST or None, instance=record)

        if projects_form.is_valid():
            projects_form.save()
            

        return render(request, 'projects_mobile.html', {'projects_form':projects_form})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In...")
        return redirect('home')
```

template.html

```
    <select name="project_num" id="project_num"> 
     <option value="2"> "2" </option>
    </select>

     <div id="projects_container" ></div> <!-- This is where projects_mobile.html is rendered -->
    
     <script>
                function load_projects (){
                $.ajaxSetup(
                    {
                data: {project_num: $('#project_num').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../update_project_mobile/",
                    //dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                    $("#projects_container").html(data); 
    
                    }
    
                });
                 }
    
    
            </script>
```

urls.py

```
...
    path('update_project_mobile/', views.update_project_mobile,name='update_project_mobile'),

...
```

projects_mobile.html

```
<body>

{{ projects_form }}

</body>
```

The form is rendering well as the content of `projects_mobile.html` displays well inside the `<div id="projects_container" ></div>` but there is no data inside the form's fields, only the placeholders are displayed.
The Database is very easy and there is an entry with the id "2" so it doesn't come from the DB search

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed `type: "POST"`, to `type: "GET"`, in the AJAX part and now it works